# Oracle Apex 5 Calendar Drop-down disappears behind column headers of the report

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

[image]In Region Position 02, I have a date picker.  Then directly below that, in the body, I have an interactive report (with no actions menu).  I made it an interactive report so that the column headers will always appear at the top of the page when the user scrolls down.  However, when I click on the calendar icon and the calendar menu drop down appears, it appears behind the headers of my interactive report.  I have tried to adjust the Z-INDEX in CSS code but that doesn't work.

One note:  On the interactive report, when I fix the headers to the report, the calendar drop-down will appear as desired.  But, the headers will disappear as the user scrolls down.  So, I have to fix the headers to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this issue has been resolved in the new version.

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=145797:21

---

Did you select the correct div to change the z-index value?

In the new version of apex, the selector of date-pop-up is div#ui-datepicker-div, to change write in this page something like this:

```
div#ui-datepicker-div {
   z-index: 99999 !important;
}
```

---

[image]